# How to group values in one column with difference <1% in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, difference

I have various time records and almost all differ slightly (a couple of seconds). To me, those very small difference are of little significance, so I would like to group the values in a column with a difference of 1% at most together.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Example:

Let's say we have this table:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>ID</th><th>Time_Sec</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>3000</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>3002</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>3003</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>4455</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>4455</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>4456</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>1000</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>1001</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>1001</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I would like to end with this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>ID</th><th>Group_AVG_Time_Sec</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>3002</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>4455</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>1001</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please add an example data from your table.

Comment: What  difference of seconds is acceptable and what is unacceptable? If 2 records differ by 3 seconds are they same? What about 5 or 10 seconds? When you say GROUP, what will you do with the repeated rows? Take the MAX age? the MIN age? the AVG age? The SUM of all ages? Be specific about your request; post some desired output

Comment: Thanks for the example data, but now please help us by explaining your logic for choosing 1001 but 4455. These values are neither the min, nor max, nor first, nor last, nor average of their sets

Comment: I had some problems figuring out how to add a table, so I've added a table with the help of HTML in the original post. 

Acceptable diffence would be in percentages for me, 1%. If thats not possible, I think 20 seconds would be the max. I would like to take the average time to show.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: OK, 20 seconds.. so if you had these times, how are they to be divided: 1000, 1010, 1019, 1021, 1029, 1039. I ask because we could chop em up like (1000, 1010, 1019), (1021, 1029, 1039) or 1000, (1010, 1019, 1021, 1029), 1039 or (1000, 1010), (1019, 1021, 1029, 1039) or...

Comment: I see my question is not as complete as I thought, this is the first post I made, so excuse me for my poor way of questioning. 

From the minimum value (1000) I would like to take up to 20 seconds and group all the values in one group. Then, from 1021, I would like to start a new group and group them up to 1040 (1039 in your example).

Comment: It's no problem; nearly every question even from experienced users has some smartass :) commenting "what about" .. I find a bit of clarity beforehand stops the experts degenerating into squabbling later. Sorry if it seemed I was trying to highlight that your question is poor - it wasn't, and I wasn't, promise!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! No problem at all, I didn't take it that way anyway. I just know how anyoing it can be if questions are incomplete, so I will try to think it though some more before posting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  TRUNC(AVG(time_sec)) as time_sec
FROM
  data
GROUP BY
  ID,
  TRUNC(time_sec/20)
```

For something that works more on percentages (and note that this doesn't output your expected results, but could possibly be made to) you could look at doing something like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  time_sec
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id,
    COALESCE(LAG(id) OVER(order by id), 0) as prev_id,
    time_sec,
    COALESCE(LAG(time_sec) OVER(order by id, time_sec), 0) as prev_time_sec
  FROM
    (
    SELECT
      ID,
      TIME_SEC
    FROM
      data
    )
  )
WHERE
  id != prev_id OR 
  ((time_sec - prev_time_sec) / time_sec) * 100 > 1
ORDER BY
  ID,
  time_sec
```

This orders the rows by ID and time, and only shows those where, compared to the row above, either the ID has changed, or the time (for that ID) is more than 1% different to the previous time. It's not however "all times within a group are within 1% of each over" because that then gets back to how you define group. Essentially this SQL collapses a series of 20 rows whose times are all 0.9% apart, into one row. If you wanted more like 10 rows, where there is row X and then each N rows after that, if its time is within 1% of the first row, it is suppressed; that's more like a ranking exercise, but it may be simpler to implement as dividing by some number and truncating to reduce the precision of all times, as per the first example

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it right away! Does something like this also work with percentual difference?  Let' say: start with the minimum time, and group all values that are between that minimum value and 1% above?

Comment: I've posted another example that does something with percentages

Comment: Caius, again thank you for your help, this really helps me a lot! The first already works very well and I will take a look at the second code more closely today.

Comment: No problems! If you feel it's the right answer for your query, you can mark it as such using the tick